# How to start a webex meeting from command line?

Tags: command-line, webex

I can start the webex program "ptoneclk.exe"; but I have to manually mouse click the green button "Start Meeting" on the Meetings Pane, then click Start Meeting again once the meeting window pops up.

I want to automate creating the meeting room, as I understand it automatically closes after being open for 24 hours.

Comment: Have you looked at the Webex documentation to see whether they support this?